# jQuery: change class of a div using onclick on multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery code that: onlick on #icon toggles parents class, and onclick on body changes changes the class back if clicked before.

What I need is to have the same thing happen when clicked on #item5 or #item4 like its clicked on #icon.

```
<div id="header_wrap">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="contact" id="ccontainer">
        <div id="form"></div>
        <div id="icon"><span id="getintouch">GET IN TOUCH</span></div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu_wrap">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="item1"><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="item2"><a  href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li id="item3"><a  href="#">What we do</a></li>
            <li id="item4"><a  href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="item5"><a  href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code....I tried writing my own to add the functionality but I can't seem to get it working.. very little experience with js/jq.

```
$('#icon').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parent()
        .toggleClass('contact')
        .toggleClass('contactexpand');
});

$('body').on('click', function(e){
    $('#ccontainer')
        .removeClass('contactexpand')
        .addClass('contact');
});

$('#ccontainer').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call event.stopPropagation from the click handler to keep it from "bubbling" up the DOM (i.e., to keep it from activating the click event on all ancestor elements).

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#icon, ul li').on('click', function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                $('#icon').parent()
                .toggleClass('contact')
                .toggleClass('contactexpand');               
            });
            $('body').on('click', function(e){

                $('#ccontainer')
                .removeClass('contactexpand')
                .addClass('contact');
            });
        });
```

Comment: That's better :-) Even had a typo after repost. Yikes. I tested it now that I am back to my computer . . . Notice how you can use any (or at least just about any) valid CSS selector as the parameter for a jQuery function call.

Comment: You need to add $('#ccontainer').on('click', function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
  Than it works! :)) just change so other people can use it maybe..thaks.
});

Comment: You are correct. Returning false not only stops propagation ('bubbling') but also prevents the default action of element that is actually being clicked. I agree that it would be more beneficial to others reading this to change returning false to calling e.stopPropagation, because otherwise someone might have returned false and been left wondering why thier element's default action was not being fired. See: http://blog.webvines.co.uk/post/3743395029/return-false-preventdefault-and-stoppropagation-in

Answer (score 0):

Change the js to:

```
$('#icon, #ul > li').on('click', function(e){
    $("#ccontainer")
      or $(this).parent() *not entirely sure what you wanted to get*
    .toggleClass('contact')
    .toggleClass('contactexpand');
});



$('body:not(#icon, #ul > li)').on('click', function(e){
    $('#ccontainer')
    .removeClass('contactexpand')
    .addClass('contact');
});


$('#ccontainer').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The `#ul > li` refers to all `#item(number)`s

Comment: not working tried it already... :(  it seems to think that on #item click is also on body click and doesnt open it...jsut triggers the page  a bit...

Comment: Changed, could you recheck?

Comment: Still doesnt work...the answer above does it perfectly with minor correction from my comment. Thanks anyway.